# Select drop down list item if value match from group label?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna add a dynamic function that will auto select the drop down list if/with any of the value that matches the input fields label?

In the snippet bellow, **Product Code** should be selected ( since label IS **Product Code**)

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Product Code</label> <select id="ddlProductCode"
    class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="0">
        --Select--
      </option>
      <option value="Product Code">
        Product Code
      </option>
      <option value="Product Name">
        Product Name
      </option>
      <option value="Product Description">
        Product Description
      </option>
      <option value="Product Category">
        Product Category
      </option>
      <option value="Product Sub Category">
        Product Sub Category
      </option>
     
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance!
Dav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check jquery that will select the value based on the label text

```js
$('#ddlProductCode option:contains(' + $('#lbl').text() +')').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == $('#lbl').text()) {
        $(this).attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="lbl" for="">Product Code</label> <select id="ddlProductCode"
    class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="0">
        --Select--
      </option>
      <option value="Product Code">
        Product Code
      </option>
      <option value="Product Name">
        Product Name
      </option>
      <option value="Product Description">
        Product Description
      </option>
      <option value="Product Category">
        Product Category
      </option>
      <option value="Product Sub Category">
        Product Sub Category
      </option>
     
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this will help:

```js
$(function() {
    var $ddlProductCode = $('#ddlProductCode');
    var labelValue = $select.prevAll("label:first").text();
    $select.val(labelValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Product Code</label> <select id="ddlProductCode"
    class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="0">
        --Select--
      </option>
      <option id="asd" value="Product Code">
        Product Code
      </option>
      <option value="Product Name">
        Product Name
      </option>
      <option value="Product Description">
        Product Description
      </option>
      <option value="Product Category">
        Product Category
      </option>
      <option value="Product Sub Category">
        Product Sub Category
      </option>
     
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every option and select the one matching the label text like this:

```
$('option').each(function(i, option) {
    if ( option.value == $('label').text() ) {
        option.selected = "selected";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < yourselect.length; ++i) {
            if (yourselect.options[i].value == yourvalue) {
                yourselect.value = yourvalue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately that's not the way you should be using the `<label>` tag.

> The HTML  element represents a caption for an item in a user
>   interface. -- [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

So, `<label>` is not meant to say what the value should be.
If you want to set a default value just add `selected` to that `<option>`.

I'm not entirely sure of why you would do this, so maybe I am misunderstanding but to answer your question you could set the `<option>` based off the label name.

There's no need to loop through the options:

```
$('#ddlProductCode').val($('label').text())
```